# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntim eClasspath' error in react native

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

Im getting this error when I run gradlew assembleRelease to generate signed apk in react native
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing minSdkVersion to 21 solved the issue